# How to get previous activity in android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Lets say my default activity is `MainActivity` and I start another activity `DepositActivity` **without** using `finish()` in `MainActivity`

Now how can I access the instance of `MainActivity` inside `DepositActivity`

Comment: Can you provide an example, why would you like to have an instance of that Activity? I am asking cause it doesn't sound like a good practice given that the background Activity can be in an undefined state (might have been destroyed by the system, etc.) and this sounds like a leak.

Comment: check this link --> https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/passing-data-between-activities-2d0ef122f19d

 //created a static variable
companion object {

}

Comment: @MarošŠeleng thank you for being the voice of reason here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now as how can I access the instance of MainActivity inside DepositActivity

**AFAIK** That is not possible to access instance of one activity in other Activity

if you have this type of requirement than Try to manage using  [**`Fragments`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to retrieve some result from `DepositActivity` use `startActivityForResult(..., DepositActivity::class.java)` method. In `MainActivity` override `onActivityResult` method:

   ```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       // retrieve data using 'data' variable
   }
   ```

   In `DepositActivity` you need to set data using method `setResult()` before finishing `DepositActivity`.
2. If you want to pass some data to `DepositActivity` use `intent` for that, for example:

   ```
   val intent = Intent(this, DepositActivity::class.java)
   intent.putExtra("Extra_Name", /*Some Data*/)
   startActivity(intent)
   ```
3. **Not Recommended**: Use static reference to `MainActivity` (don't forget to delete it in `onDestroy()` method):

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      companion object {
           @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
           @JvmStatic
           var instance: MainActivity? = null
      }

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           instance = this
      }

      override fun onDestroy() {
          instance = null
          super.onDestroy()
      }
   }
   ```

   In `DepositActivity` you can access it like this:

   ```
   MainActivity.instance?./* call some method or property */
   ```

   **But you should not rely on `onDestroy()` being called, cause [there are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()) So you can have memory leak**

Comment: I'm glad that you put "Not recommended" in bold, but my opinion is that you shouldn't have posted it at all. Moreover, you should not rely on `onDestroy()` being called, cause [There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()), thus **StaticFieldLeak** lint warning that you suppress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare as **companion object** variable and method  in MainActivity. Static type of variables and methods are declared as **companion object** in Kotlin.

Look at below example,

Declare variables and methods in MainActivity,

```
val value : String = "hello from Main"

companion object {

    lateinit var instance : MainActivity

    fun getInstancem() : MainActivity {

        return instance
    }
}
```

Use this instance and print value in **DepositActivity** like,

```
Log.d("log_in_second_activity", "message " + MainActivity.getInstancem().value)
```

You can see log message.

Hope this will give you hint.